# How do I add tailwindcss to an electron forge vite project

Tags: javascript, electron, tailwind-css, vite

I added tailwindcss to the vite project as usual, but it failed, it's not [working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxIEh.png)

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

npx tailwindcss init -p

electron-forge start
```

The last tailwindcss isn't working.

Comment: please use browserify and convert you nodejs code to plain javascript `browserify main.js -o bundle.js` now use this `bundle.js` for your electron forge project. https://browserify.org/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.